# Cannot launch a new process on new desktop created using CreateDesktop Windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I am trying to launch a new process 'calc.exe' on a new desktop on Windows 10. When I try to switch the desktop the screen becomes black(Looks like its a new desktop with no background). It then switches back to primary desktop as expected and I see the calc.exe launched there. Below is the code snippet. I am using Visual Studio 2015 for development. Why calc.exe does not launch on second desktop?

```
    HDESK originalDesktop;
    HDESK secondaryDesktop;
    originalDesktop = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
    LPWSTR secondaryDesktopName = L"Mysecondary";
    secondaryDesktop = CreateDesktop(secondaryDesktopName,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        DF_ALLOWOTHERACCOUNTHOOK,
        DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP |
        DESKTOP_READOBJECTS |
        DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW |
        DESKTOP_CREATEMENU |
        DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL |
        DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD |
        DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK |
        DESKTOP_ENUMERATE |
        DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS,
        nullptr);
    //SetThreadDesktop(secondaryDesktop);
    SwitchDesktop(secondaryDesktop);
    DWORD r = 0;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    bool processCreated;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.lpDesktop = secondaryDesktopName;
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    DWORD dwCreationFlags = CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB; // | CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;

    const LPWSTR calculatorExe = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe";
    processCreated = CreateProcess(calculatorExe,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        TRUE,
        0,
        //dwCreationFlags,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        &si,
        &pi);
    //Sleep(4000);
    if (!processCreated)
    {
        //logerror
        r = GetLastError();
        fprintf(stderr, "\n\nError while creating %S process, Code: %d\n\n", calculatorExe, r);
        return r;
    }

    r = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    //GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &r);

    int i=INT_MIN;
    while (i < INT_MAX) i++;//Add some delay so that calc.exe //gets launched
    //while (i > INT_MIN) i--;
    SwitchDesktop(originalDesktop);
    ///////////////////////

    CloseDesktop(secondaryDesktop);
```

I tried launching notepad.exe and it works. Not sure about calc.exe.

Comment: Does this happen with `notepad.exe` too?

Comment: Thanks conio. I tried with notepad.exe and it gets launched correctly. I am surprised now. Any ideas for why this happened or debugging this issue with calc.exe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows 10 the Calculator is a Store/UWP app.

`calc.exe` is a small stub that launches the real Calculator (perhaps using the [Application Activation Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706902(v=vs.85).aspx)). The real Calculator is launched by a Windows service that knows nothing about your desktop.

That's also the reason your wait is satisfied so fast. `calc.exe` asks to launch the real Calculator app and exits.